# HTML extract all text and left number only

Tags: html

is it possible to extract all the text and leave number only from an user input?

For example:

```
user input :iifjeut"890977665", ewrusdf
sdfiue"998877655",sarowerisdferu8574669
```

The output is :

```
 890977665 (break line)
 998877655 (break line)
 8574669 (break line)
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'm thinking Regex will be useful, and you'll have to rely on JS.

Comment: Checout http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/vqjKt/1/ working demo

Comment: This is not possible with HTML, so you need to specify whether you want to do this with client-side scripting, server-side scripting (which technology), or both. Or, rather, specify that *and* show your best attempt at doing it so far, and how it fails to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can't do this only with HTML/HTML5*.  You need to use scripting language like **`Javascript`** like

1) Using `regex` **`match()`** you can get the digits from the user's input. (note: `g` represents globally) 
2) Using `for` iteration, add **`br`** tags to each array's element.

Finally,

```
var text = 'iifjeut"890977665", ewrusdfsdfiue"998877655",sarowerisdferu8574669';
text = text.match(/\d+/g);
var final = "";
for (var i=0; i< text.length; i++) {
    final += text[i] + "</br>";
}
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = final;
```

**Output:**

```
890977665
998877655
8574669
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/OwapiQo/2/)

**Offline Coding:** (based on your comments)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>A simple JS</title> 
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
   <script>
    var text = 'iifjeut"890977665", ewrusdfsdfiue"998877655",sarowerisdferu8574669';
    text = text.match(/\d+/g);
    var final = "";
    for (var i=0; i< text.length; i++) {
      final += text[i] + "</br>";
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = final;    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sry, i m very new for this...can u answer me full code...how to get the result..thx very much

Comment: @user2978122 I have updated my answer, check it.  let me know if you find any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the numbers from string use this with javascript

```
var itemId = document.getElementById('<%=textbox.clientid%>').innerHTML.match(/\d+/)[0]
```